# html tags are not applying in angularjs ckeditor instead of it is showing html element tag code in ediator

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ckeditor

```
//My controller code
```

//I am getting values from database into angular js ckeditor but html tags are not applying in editor instead of it is showing html element tag code in ediator

```
myApp.directive('ckEditor', [function () {
   return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function ($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {

     var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);

     ck.on('pasteState', function () {
      $scope.$apply(function () {
       ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
      });
     });
     ngModel.$render = function () {
      ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
     };
    }
   };
  }])

        myApp.controller('editcontentcontroller', function ($scope, $http)
   {
      $scope.ckEditors;
    $http({ method: 'POST', url: 'pageedit.php' }).success(function (data)
    {
        // response data 
       $scope.id = data[0]['id'];
      $scope.page = data[0]['page'];
      $scope.ckEditors = data[0]['pagecontent'];
     }).
     error(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
     });
  });
```

Comment: are you able to resolve issue by following solution? please provide your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add following into your directive and check the CKEDITOR docs

```
 ck.on('instanceReady', function () {
      ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
  });
```

[CKEDITOR.instanceReady](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-instanceReady) Fired when a CKEDITOR instance is created, fully initialized and ready for interaction.

```
    myApp.directive('ckEditor', function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            priority: 10,
            link: function (scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
                var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);

                if (!ngModel) return;

                ck.on('instanceReady', function () {
                    ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
                });

                function updateModel() {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        if (ck.getData().length) {
                            ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
                        }
                    });
                }

                ck.on('change', updateModel);
                ck.on('key', updateModel);
                ck.on('dataReady', updateModel);
                ck.on('pasteState', updateModel);

                ngModel.$render = function (value) {
                    ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
                };
            }
        };
    })
```